# How to know a friends who achieve this achievement?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, achievements

Cant find the way to display friends, who achieve it, on achievement page.

- /USER_ID/achievements - returns users achievements
- /FRIEND_ID/achievements - returns one of my friend achievements
- /APP_ID/achievements - returns list of defines

Help me please! Do I need to do many requests for each my friend (I think it is not good way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to retrieve the friends' achievements individually.

You can call `/achievements?ids=[CSV_LIST_OF_FRIENDS]` though - and calling `/[USER]/friends?fields=installed` will show you which friends have the app installed to help you limit the number of IDs you need to include in the CSV list in the first query.